# Getting random key from Map based on the probabilities of the value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `map<string,float>` of size 10000. The values(float) are the probabilities of that key(string), non-negative entries that add up to one.

E.g. Key(Value): `A(0.5);B(0.3);C(0.2)`

How would you get a random key based on the probability `vector` (I know I do not have a vector) e.g. `{0.5,0.3,0.2}`?

I can use `C++11`.

Thank you.

Comment: The first step would seem to be to get a random value between 0 and 1. Then, since you are searching by value, the only thing you can do is iterate over the values.

Answer (score 1):

Create an additional map whose keys are cumulative probabilities and the values are iterators into the first map or just the string you want. For example: 0(A), 0.5(B), 0.8(C). Then generate a random value between 0 and 1, and finally use [`lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/) on the second map with that value.

Comment: [std::partial_sum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) is helpful for the first part

Comment: @Caleth Good idea, but that starts off by one (for `lower_bound` you would need your first entry to be zero), and it directly dereferences iterators. IMO it would be easier to hand-write a loop than contort everything to get the algorithm to work. Actually, I often find that.

Comment: You just need a functor like `float acc = 0.0; auto exclusive_plus = [&acc](float lhs, float rhs) { swap(lhs, acc); return lhs + rhs; }`. Or an equivalent to c++17's `std::exclusive_scan`